# How can I select ID and get a value of it in input data in this row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

here is what I want to do.

When I click the modify button, I wish div that contains role of 'ucomment' changes into in-line input form with its original value typed.

But I can't even start with selecting the div.

I thought the code here would work and could select what I aimed, but it didn't.

```
$(this).closest("div[role='ucomment']")
```

How can I select the div here?

```
<ul id="comments" class="list-group">
<script id="commentTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each list}}
      <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          <div class="row w-100">
            <div class="col-2" name="uid">{{uid}}</div>
            <div class="col-8" role="ucomment" name="ucomment">{{ucomment}}</div>
            <div class="col-2" name="regdate">{{prettifyDate regdate}}</div>
          </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="modifyComment()">Modify</button> 
            <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="deleteComment()">Delete</button> 
        <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">14</span>
      </li>
    {{/each }}
</script>
</ul>
        <button id="sendForm" type="submit" class="btn btn-info" onclick="addComment()">Send</button>
        <button id="cancel" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#openNew">Cancel</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please note that I am using handlebar library, that's why there is {{# each}} tag

Comment: `closest()` works only upwards in the DOM. It traverses the parent elements.

Comment: @connexo And Button isn't a child of the div with w-100 class ?

Comment: Exactly. Check my answer. Even if the button were a child of that div, closest() still doesn't check for siblings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should find you the `div`:

```
this.closest("li").querySelector("div[role='ucomment']")
```

`closest()` works only upwards in the DOM. It traverses the parent elements. So what you can find using it is `li`, from there you can use `find()` using the selector `div[role='ucomment']` you tried to pass to `closest()`.

```js
// get a NodeList containing alls modify buttons and convert it to an array
const modifyBtns = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.btn.btn-modify'));

// iterate over each button...
for (const modifyBtn of modifyBtns) {
  // and attach an event listener for click, binding the handler to each modifyBtn
  modifyBtn.addEventListener('click', modifyComment.bind(modifyBtn));
}

function modifyComment(e) {
  this.closest("li").querySelector("div[role='ucomment']").style.color= 'red';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="row w-100">
      <div class="col-8" role="ucomment" name="ucomment1">{{ucomment}}</div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-modify">Modify</button>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="row w-100">
      <div class="col-8" role="ucomment" name="ucomment2">{{ucomment}}</div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-modify">Modify</button>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="row w-100">
      <div class="col-8" role="ucomment" name="ucomment1">{{ucomment}}</div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-modify">Modify</button>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="row w-100">
      <div class="col-8" role="ucomment" name="ucomment2">{{ucomment}}</div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-modify">Modify</button>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="row w-100">
      <div class="col-8" role="ucomment" name="ucomment1">{{ucomment}}</div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-modify">Modify</button>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="row w-100">
      <div class="col-8" role="ucomment" name="ucomment2">{{ucomment}}</div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-modify">Modify</button>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="row w-100">
      <div class="col-8" role="ucomment" name="ucomment1">{{ucomment}}</div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-modify">Modify</button>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="row w-100">
      <div class="col-8" role="ucomment" name="ucomment2">{{ucomment}}</div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-modify">Modify</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Edit: By the looks of it using the in line eventhandler `onclick` won't pass the event, so I changed your code to vanilla JS instead of jQuery (apparently closest in jQuery doesn't work the way plain JS closest works). Since using inline event handlers is considered bad practice anyway (that's what `addEventListener()` is for), you should change that anyway.

Comment: But it also doesn't select the div I aimed.

Comment: I am not sure if `$(this).closest("li").find("div[role='ucomment']")` works because it doesn't do anything when I do `if ($(this).closest("li").find("div[role='ucomment']").length) {alert("alert")}`.

Comment: Which button do you want the functionality on? I coded so your modify button has this ability.

Comment: As you did with code snippet. By the way, why can't `$(this).closest("li").find("div[role='ucomment']")` work in this way?

Comment: I assume it's because `this` is not what you're expecting it to be. I addressed that by explicitly setting `this` using `.bind(modifyBtn)`. You can also use `e.target` instead of `this`, which would make the call to `bind()` unnecessary. If you want that, you need to define `e` as the parameter that `modifyComment` expects.

Comment: Added many list items to show you're getting exactly the DIV you want.

Comment: Oh.. Thanks. But can you please revert the change when there was only one example? I have not really studied Front skills and want to check about addEventListener.

Comment: I edited some comments into the code that should help you understand what's going on. Let me know if anything remains unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use plain javascript for this?

```
document.getElementsByName("ucomment")[0];
```

Let me know if this works.

Then you can use jQuery's click function to get the clicking element and check if the clicked element is a "div" and do whatever the things you want to do.

```
$("*", document.body).click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var domElement = $(this).get(0);
  if (domElement.tagName == "div") {
    //do what you want to do here
   }
});
```

Comment: Can't use this because there will be a loop for handlebars{{#each}}.. So there will be more than one that has role attribute with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on button that call modifyComment() you need up to parent and find your div.
try to change html onclick and function

```
<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="modifyComment(this)">Modify</button>

    function modifyComment(elem) {
            let parent = $(elem).parent();

            parent.find($("div[role='ucomment']")).css("background", "red");
            console.log(parent);
        }
```

Or if you change html button then inside function modifyComment

```
$(element).parent().find("div[role='ucomment']").css("background-color","red")
```

Comment: This doesn't work either because nothing happened when I do `$(this).parent().find("div[role='ucomment']").css("background-color","yellow")`

Comment: On which button you click ?

Comment: modify button and I expected the div at the left side of the button should change. but it didn't

Comment: I changed my answer. Try it.